# Loss is oscillating and not minimizing

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, loss-function

I am training a simple attention network with stored extracted ResNet features. Every gigapixel image is divided into approximately 20000 patches of size 256x256, and each patch is associated with a feature vector from custom ResNet50. Now, my shape of data for every image will be [20000, 1024].
The train data loader loads a gigapixel image at a time, making the batch size 1.
Reference: [Code](https://github.com/mahmoodlab/CLAM/)

**Model**

```
class Attn_Net_Gated(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, L = 1024, D = 256, dropout = False, n_classes = 1):
      super(Attn_Net_Gated, self).__init__()
        self.attention_a = [
            nn.Linear(L, D),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(D), 
            nn.Tanh()]
        self.attention_b = [nn.Linear(L, D),
                            nn.BatchNorm1d(D),
                            nn.Sigmoid()]
        if dropout:
            self.attention_a.append(nn.Dropout(0.25))
            self.attention_b.append(nn.Dropout(0.25))
        self.attention_a = nn.Sequential(*self.attention_a)
        self.attention_b = nn.Sequential(*self.attention_b)
        self.attention_c = nn.Linear(D, n_classes) 

    def forward(self, x):
        a = self.attention_a(x)
        b = self.attention_b(x)
        A = a.mul(b) 
        A = self.attention_c(A)  
        return A, x 

class MB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gate = True, size_arg = "small", dropout = False, k_sample=8, n_classes=2,
        instance_loss_fn=nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), subtyping=True):
        nn.Module.__init__(self) 
        self.size_dict = {"small": [1024, 512, 256], "big": [1024, 512, 384]} #choosing the model size 
        size = self.size_dict[size_arg] 
        fc =[]
        if gate:
            attention_net = Attn_Net_Gated(L = size[0], D = size[2], dropout = dropout, n_classes = n_classes) 
        fc.append(attention_net)
        self.attention_net = nn.Sequential(*fc)
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.subtyping = subtyping
        initialize_weights(self)
def relocate(self):
        device=torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    def forward(self, h, label=None, instance_eval=False, return_features=False, attention_only=False):
        device = h.device
        A, h = self.attention_net(h)         
        A = torch.transpose(A, 1, 0)  
        if attention_only:
            return A, h
```

**Utils**

```
def get_split_loader(split_dataset, training = False, testing = False, weighted = False):
    """
        return either the validation loader or training loader 
    """
    kwargs = {'num_workers': 4} if device.type == "cuda" else {}
    if not testing:
        if training:
            if weighted:
                weights = make_weights_for_balanced_classes_split(split_dataset)
                loader = DataLoader(split_dataset, batch_size=1, sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights, len(weights)), collate_fn = collate_MIL_tr, **kwargs) 
            else:
                loader = DataLoader(split_dataset, batch_size=1, sampler = RandomSampler(split_dataset), collate_fn = collate_MIL_tr, **kwargs)
        else:
            loader = DataLoader(split_dataset, batch_size=1, sampler = SequentialSampler(split_dataset), collate_fn = collate_MIL_tr, **kwargs)
    
    else:
        ids = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(split_dataset), int(len(split_dataset)*0.1)), replace = False)
        loader = DataLoader(split_dataset, batch_size=1, sampler = SubsetSequentialSampler(ids), collate_fn = collate_MIL_tr, **kwargs )

    return loader
def get_optim(model, args):
    if args.opt == "adam":
        optimizer = optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=args.lr, weight_decay=args.reg)
    elif args.opt == 'sgd':
        optimizer = optim.SGD(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=args.lr, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=args.reg)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
    return optimizer
def initialize_weights(module):
    for m in module.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight) 
            m.bias.data.zero_() 
        elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm1d):
            nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
```

**Training**

```
def train(datasets, cur, args):
    train_split, val_split, test_split = datasets
    save_splits(datasets, ['train', 'val', 'test'], os.path.join(args.results_dir, 'splits_{}.csv'.format(cur)))
    model = MB(**model_dict, instance_loss_fn=instance_loss_fn)     
    model.relocate()
    optimizer = get_optim(model, args)
    train_loader = get_split_loader(train_split, training=True, testing = args.testing, weighted = args.weighted_sample)
    val_loader = get_split_loader(val_split,  testing = args.testing)
    test_loader = get_split_loader(test_split, testing = args.testing)
    if args.early_stopping:
        print('yes')
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience = 20, stop_epoch=50, verbose = True)
    else:
        early_stopping = None
    for epoch in range(args.max_epochs):
        if args.model_type in ['mmb'] and not args.no_inst_cluster:     
            epoch_loss = train_loop(epoch, model, train_loader, optimizer, args.n_classes, args.bag_weight, writer, loss_fn)
            stop, val_loss = validate(cur, epoch, model, val_loader, args.n_classes, early_stopping, writer, loss_fn, args.results_dir)     
        if stop:  
            break
    if args.early_stopping:
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join(args.results_dir, "s_{}_checkpoint.pt".format(cur))))
    else:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(args.results_dir, "s_{}_checkpoint.pt".format(cur)))
    return epoch_loss, val_loss

def train_loop(epoch, model, loader, optimizer, n_classes, bag_weight, writer = None, loss_fn = None):
    device=torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.
    for batch_idx, (data, label, coordinates, slide_id) in enumerate(loader): 
        data, label = data.to(device), label.to(device)
        pred_val, h_feat = model(data, label = label, attention_only = True)
        target_val = #this is an array that I obtain from some interpolation and has the same shape of pred_val
        l2_loss = coeff * torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(pred_val.unsqueeze(0), target_val.unsqueeze(0))
        epoch_loss +=  l2_loss.item()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        l2_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    epoch_loss = epoch_loss / len(loader)
    print('Epoch: {}, train_loss: {:.4f} '.format(epoch, epoch_loss))
    return epoch_loss
```

The train loss oscillates and gets stuck within a fixed range of values as follows and does not minimize at all:
[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF2FM.png)

NOTE: I have tried the above experiments for Learning rates ranging from 1e-2 to 1e-6; Weight decay from 1e-3 to 1e-6; for optimizers both Adam and SGD; epochs from 50 to 200 (with and without early stopping). The loss graph for all the experiments conducted so far are similar to the above snapshot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is minimal, and it’s done mimimizing. It’s hard to know what is going on without knowing what problem you’re working on.

Comment: Could you give an example of your data ? How many data do you have in your dataset ?

Comment: The dataset has ~500 gigapixel images in the training set, and each image is divided into ~20000 patches.

Comment: [UPDATE]: I caught the problem in the training process. The computational graph was broken in the training loop. This was hampering the gradient propagation, and I solved that issue. Sometimes, an unforeseen and seemingly trivial bug is annoying.